# If statement configuration with multiple variables in an email

Tags: php, if-statement

After someone registers to my site, they have to be given permission to join it. I have setup a group database table that if someone is group level 1, they cannot access the site. Then if someone is group level 2-5 they can. Whenever I change that group level, I want to send them an email. The email is working fine, but I cannot figure out how to do this:

I want whichever group level is being sent over to my php file 2-6, to be given a different message and to echo out the variables I am assigning. So if someone has been granted group level 2, I want this part of my email...

```
<p>You have been put into the permission category of </p><br>
```

To say

```
<p>You have been put into the permission category of Spectator. This level of permission allows you to do basic site tasks</p><br>
```

I'm just not sure how to structure this, so that it varies per user and group level granted.

How can I make this work?

```
if($change_group = 2) {
    $group2 = "Spectator";
    $group2Message = "This level of permission allows you to do basic site taks....."
}
if($change_group = 3) {
    $group3 = "Team Member";
    $group3Message = "This level of permission allows ....."
}
if($change_group = 4) {
    $group4 = "Commissioner";
    $group4Message = "This level of permission allows ....."
}
if($change_group = 6) {
    $group6 = "Denied";
    $group6Message = "This level of permission allows ....."
}
        $to = $email;
        $subject = 'Permission Status';
        $message = '
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Group Change</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Hi '.$firstname.',</p><br>
            <p>You have been added to the group.. </p><br>
```

Comment: First, you need '==' comparison operator, not '='. And second, why creating 4,x... different variables? You need two: $group, and $group_message, and just insert that into email  body, like you did with $firstname var....

Comment: When I do this, it grabs the last if statement and puts that variable into the email. I selected group 2 which is Spectator and it took group 6, Denied.

Comment: Be sure that you have right variable type! Is $change_group really integer? You have process described in answer bellow. It should work....

Comment: A 1 for some reason? The correct value is being updated in my db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `if($change_group = 2)` returns true, because it successfully assigns the variable `$change_group` to the value 2. Use `==` instead, this checks if the value equals to 2.

This is a good place to use a `switch` instead of a series of `if`-statements, but there's nothing wrong with doing it this way.

```
 if ($change_group == 2) {
     $groupname = "Spectator";
     $groupmessage = "do basic site tasks";
 } elseif ($change_group == 3) {
     $groupname = "Team Member";
     $groupmessage = "do other tasks";
 } elseif ($change_group == 4) {
     $groupname = "Commissioner";
     $groupmessage = "act like a boss";
 } elseif ($change_group == 6) {
     $groupname = "Denied";
     $groupmessage = "be denied";
 }
```

And then your `$message`is set to something like this

```
 $message = '
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Group Change</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <p>Hi '.$firstname.',</p><br>
    <p>You have been put into the permission category of '.$groupname.'! This level of permissions allows you to '.$groupmessage.'.</p><br>';
```

Then you'll just have to format it the way you want it!

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect. Thanks! I'll have to look into switches. I've never used them before. I appreciate it!

Comment: Alright, I'll gladly help you troubleshoot. If you `echo $change_group;` before the `if`-statements, what does it echo out?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that I forgot to add some `;` when I wrote this code - did your remember to add that? Specifically I forgot that after the `$groupmessage`?

Comment: Yes, I added all of those. I didn't copy and paste your code, I just made the few changes to mine.

Comment: Alright. Did you echo out the variable, what is it set to?

Comment: My comment must have failed. Yes, I echoed it out and am getting one for everything, but the correct value is being placed into my db? And that uses the same `$change_group` variable?

Comment: The way PHP works, it will only execute code if all parameters return ture, so if it's running the code for group 2, then the variable is 2. If you echo it out (or use var_dump) just before the if-statement, what does it print?

Comment: It comes up bool(true) foir var_dump($change_group);

Comment: Then your variable is not an integer, it's a boolean - and that's your error. You need to look where `$change_group` is changed, and make sure that it's actually an int (integer) with the proper values. If you need further help with that, we can move this to a chat and I'll gladly help you out.

Comment: Nevermind. I hate this `if($change_group = 2 || $change_group = 3 || $change_group = 4 || $change_group = 5) {
  $status = "approved";
 } else {
  "denied";` above it that was throwing it off. I commented that out and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a bunch of elseifs, or even a switch, another possibility is to create an array of groups, and pull from the array based on the `$change_group` value.

```
<?php
$groups = array(
    2 => array('name' => 'Spectator', 'message' => 'This level of permission allows you...'),
    3 => array('name' => 'Team Member', 'message' => 'This level of permission allows ...'),
    4 => array('name' => 'Commissioner', 'message' => 'This level of permission allows ...'),
    6 => array('name' => 'Denied', 'message' => 'This level of permission allows ...')
);

'<p>You have been added to the group '.$groups[$change_group]['name']
    .' '.$groups[$change_group]['message'].'</p><br>';
```

Eventually you probably will want to store these values in a database rather than hard coding them.